# No overload for method 'ReadLine' arguments when only 1 argument is given

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to read the first line in a file, but I keep getting this error every time I do sr.ReadLine(1); and I can not find an answer to this error.
My code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(DataStore))
                    {
                        string Conent;
                        Conent = sr.ReadLine(1);

                    };
```

Comment: Do just a sr.ReadLine(). You cant define a number in that method. Please read the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I just had and solve a problem like you're facing. Just code

```
sr.Readline()
```

Also you might wanna add some Error minimization if you're going to read it line by line in a while/loop like this.

```
while ((content = sr.Readline()) !=n null && (line != ""))
{
your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.8), the method should be called with no parameters i.e.

```
sr.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I just noticed I spelled content conent!

Comment: Wait, it gives me the same error when I try to do the second line.

Comment: @Echo Please read the docs very carefully. The second line will be read exactly as you read the first line before - with the exact same line of code *sr.ReadLine();*